# Doesn't work custom login page in django 1.7

Tags: django, email, view, authentication

I want to create my own login page uses the e-mail address and password in django 1.7.
When complete box and I click "login" page back to the login page.

My view:

```
def get_user_by_email(email):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None


def login_by_email(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    username = get_user_by_email(email)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active():
            login(request, email)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:dashboard"))
    return render_to_response('myapp/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My url:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login_by_email, name='login'),
```

My template login.html

```
{% block content %}
<form class="form-horizontal" name="LoginForm" action="{% url 'myapp:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="email" value="{{email}}" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
username = get_user_by_email(email)
```

Should be:

```
user_instance = get_user_by_email(email)
if user_instance:
    username = user_instance.username
```

You are passing the user object to authenticate and it isn't able to log the user in.
Also, when you call the login function, you should pass the user as parameter:

```
login(request, user)
```

You are currently passing the email (django can't handle it this way)

Refer to the auth [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) for more detail on how to handle custom login mechanisms

**EDIT: Here's the complete view code**

```
def get_user_by_email(email):
try:
    return User.objects.get(email=email)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    return None


def login_by_email(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user_instance = get_user_by_email(email)
    if user_instance:
        username = user_instance.username
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("myapp:dashboard"))
    return render_to_response('myapp/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Explain what's not working, so I can further help you

Comment: This code give the same results:

`def login_by_email(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user_instance = get_user_by_email(email)
    if user_instance:
        username = user_instance.username
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active():
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('freedays:dashboard'))
    return render_to_response('freedays/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: Not the code. What does the server output? Are you being redirected to the same page? Are you positive the credentials and/or email you are providing are correct? Is the first query returning something?

Comment: yes, I am redirected on the same page, and from server I get:
`[09/Feb/2015 05:40:56] "POST /myapp/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15464`

Comment: The credentials must be wrong then... does User.objects.get(email=email) return a user object?

Comment: Yes, User.objects.get(email=email) give my user object. User object is a superuser.

Comment: Keep in mind user.is_active is a models.BooleanField, not a function. Did you change that?

Comment: Yes I changed that, result is the same - I'm redirected on login page.

Comment: I get an error: local variable 'username' referenced before assignment

Comment: That is bc your function isn't returning a User object. I'll fix the code to avoid the error, but your credentials might be wrong